# How to clear the value of ReactJS datepicker

Tags: reactjs

I have used ReactJS Datepicker in my application.

```
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="planned-date">Planned Start Date * </label>
              <DatePicker selected={this.state.plannedStartDate}  value={data.plannedStartDate} onChange={this.handleChangeDate.bind(this,"plannedStartDate")} minDate={moment()} id="plannedStartDate" placeholderText="yyyy/mm/dd" isClearable={true}/>
            </div>
```

Clicking on the field is giving me the calendar. I want to know how can I clear the value of input field. Because as soon as i will click on input it will give me the calendar..so no option to press backspace or delete button from keyboard. So how we can delete the selected date. I used `isClearable={true}`, but it didn't helped. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you post the npm package your are using?

Comment: "react-datepicker": "^0.53.0"

Comment: Does isClearable show the Cross button?

Comment: No..it doesn't !!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-hofstadter-lbhm6, its working in codesandbox

Comment: @CAS yes it does

Answer (score -1):

you can try using `input = {true}` property can clear using delete or backspace button.

Comment: This is not helping. For using backspace or delete button, we should have focus on input field..But as soon as I am clicking on input field, getting datepicker calendar..so no chances of using backspace/delete.

Comment: I have used this only earlier...<DatePicker selected={this.state.plannedStartDate}  value={data.plannedStartDate} onChange={this.handleChangeDate.bind(this,"plannedStartDate")} minDate={moment()} id="plannedStartDate" placeholderText="yyyy/mm/dd" input = {true}/>

Comment: okay but I tired with your code as well                                                                                           https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-chatterjee-yf1rh                                                        Please look at your version of react-date-picker